# C++ string not concatenating char when int even though it is a char

Tags: c++, string, file, parsing, io

Here is my runnable code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc > 1) { // passed in parameter
        ifstream file(argv[1]); // create file from second parameter

        string line;

        if (file) { // file exists and has been opened
            //stack *stmt = new stack();
            while (getline(file, line)) {                   // run through lines of file
                string word = "";
                cout << "LINE: " << line << endl;
                for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {   // run through char of line
                    char ch = line[i];
                    if (ch == ' ') {
                        if (word == "") {
                             continue;
                        } else {
                            //stmt->push(word);
                            cout << "\x1b[34;1mWORD: " << word << "\x1b[0m" << end;
                            word = "";
                        }
                    } else {
                        word += ch;
                    }
                }
            }

            cout << stmt->size() << endl;
            while (stmt->has_next()) {
                cout << stmt->pop() << endl;
            }
        } else {
            cerr << "\x1b[31;1mNo such file, \x1b[21m" << argv[1] << "\x1b[0m" << endl;
        }
    } else { // no parameters passed in
        cerr << "\x1b[31;1mYou did not specify any files to parse\x1b[0m" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It seems straight forward. However, when the character, `ch`, is the character for an integer (like `'0'` to `'9'`), the character simply is not appended.

Does this happen with you guys (if you create a test file like so:

```
this  is from     line 1
line 2
3
```

and then after `g++ test.cpp` - if you name file `test.cpp` - and `./a.out test` - if you store the above test file to `test` - you will see (frustratingly so) that `WORD: ...` (in blue) *never* contains a number if the number is a single character.

I.E. `OUTPUT` for me:

```
LINE: this  is from     line 1
WORD: this
WORD: is
WORD: from
WORD: line
LINE: line 2
WORD: line
LINE: 3
```

This is very frustrating; please help and explain why it is not working or comment that it works for you.

Comment: NOTE: this is for linux; probably will have lots of annoying plain-text ANSI escape sequences on Windows.

Comment: So what exactly should the output be?

Comment: Even when a word is simply a character that represents an int (`'1'`, `'3'`, etc.) it should still be printed after `WORD: ` (because it is still a word); however, it is not

Comment: So your input is line2424523523 for example, and it stops after 'line' ?

Comment: You only print a word when you see a space. But there isn't a space at the end of a line.

Comment: The output you've described does not correspond to the input.  Also, all three digits are being output.  You are going to need to give (1) a complete example of working code  (2) an example of input (3) an example of output that corresponds to the actual input  and (4) a description of how they differ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that words are printed only if there is a space after them:

```
if (ch == ' ') {
    ....
        cout << "\x1b[34;1mWORD: " << word << "\x1b[0m" << end;
    ....
}
```

This is not the case for the numbers in the given test.